# Woocommerce + Multilingual: How to get current currency

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

I'm building an online shop with Woocommerce and the multilanguage plugin (and activated multi-currency).

The built-in currency switcher works like a charm, but I wonder if there is any way to get the current active currency in PHP? Are there some globals like ICL_LANGUAGE_CODE?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I figured it out: simply use `get_woocommerce_currency()` to get the the currency code (e.g. USD or EUR)